# ASP.NET can't apply style on a '<a>' tag

Tags: html, css, asp.net, razor, .net-6.0

I want to design a navbar in the "_Layout.cshtml" of an ASP.NET project. The css in the "_Layout.cshtml.css" works fine on every element, but the `<a>` tag. I want to remove the underline of the link. The cshtml-file looks like this:

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">Home</a>
</li>
```

I tried something like this in the css file:

```
a {
    text-decoration : none; 
}
//and this
.nav-link {
    text-decoration : none;
}
```

I also tried to put the content of the `<a>` tab betwenn a `<span>` tag. But didn't change anything.
Why does the `<a>` tag ignore my css?

Comment: It could be that there's a rule for `a.nav-link` which takes priority over your rule for `a` or `.nav-link`. So try a rule for `a.nav-link`. If that doesn't work, try `text-decoration : none !important;`. Adding the `!important` gives the rule more priority.

Comment: Yeah, it seams like something is overriding my `a.nav-link` class of my css stylesheet. If I declare the css-class in a `<style>` tag in the cshtml-doc, everything works like it should.

Comment: How is that possible? There is no `a.nav-link` selector in your CSS file. Ayway, the order in which you include CSS in your page is also important. Later styling overrides previous styling. You can see all the styling in a page with the [browser's developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/Tools_and_setup/What_are_browser_developer_tools).

Comment: Hi @Mabadabadu, how is your whole _Layout.cshtml like? When I use the default asp.net core project, the _Layout contains such tab and it does not contain any underline.

Answer (score 0):

If you have added bootstrap try this

`<a class="nav-link text-decoration-none" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">Home</a>`

or

add this in css file

```
.text-decoration-none{
    text-decoration : none !important;
}
```

then

```
<a class="nav-link text-decoration-none" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">Home</a>
```

Comment: The new class an the `!important` statement, don't change anything.

Comment: Drop all _layout style file hear